# vue js multiple dynamic selects population issue

Tags: javascript, select, dynamic, vue.js, multi-select

Hello there vue js guru's

Currently i'm creating some wizard with a little bit more "advanced" setup and need some help getting the correct outcome. I tried a few different methods but not with any success yet.

**What i'm trying to do is the following:**

I'm building a workout create wizard where it's possible to add sections and inside each section you could define one or more movements where each movement itself should have some sort of measurement this last one should change based on the selected movement and could have one or more options as an select to.

The data is fetched by axios (remotely) and saved to the data array for available movements like so:

```
[
    '' => [
        1 => [
            'name' => 'pull ups',
            'measure' => [
                0 => 'none',
                1 => 'distance',
            ],
        ],
        2 => [
            'name' => 'push ups',
            'measure' => [
                0 => 'none',
                1 => 'weight',
            ],
        ],
        ...
    ],
    ...
]
```

this will then be stored in the `this.movements = data.movements;` data array in my vue js instance.

Here is my vue js code:

```
<script>
new Vue({
    el: '#workout-wrapper',
    data() {
        return {
            dynamicOptions: [],

            name: null,
            sections: [{
                name: null,
                rounds: null,
                minutes: null,
                measure: null,
                movements: [{
                    reps: null,
                    movement: null,
                    measure: null,
                    remarks: null
                }]
            }],
            movements: [],
            ...
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ...
        onMovementChange(group, movement) {
            // TODO: this one combined with the computed options still isn't working correctly

            if (group == '') {
                this.options = { section: 0, movement: 0, options: this.movements[""][movement].measure };
            } else {
                this.options = { section: 0, movement: 0, options: this.movements[group][movement].measure };
            }
        },
        ...
    },
    computed: {
        options: {
            get(event, data) {
                // TODO: now we should only return the options for section and movement indexes

                return this.dynamicOptions;
            },
            set(data) {
                this.dynamicOptions[data.section] = [];
                this.dynamicOptions[data.section][data.movement] = data.options;
                // console.log(this.dynamicOptions);
            }
        }
    },
    created() {
        axios.get('/workouts/create/data').then(response => {
            let data = response.data;
            this.movements = data.movements;
            ...
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

And here the template:

```
<div class="row m-t-20" v-for="(section, index) in sections">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card card-default no-border">
        <div class="card-header separator">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Section name</label>
                        <div class="input-group m-b-15">
                            <input type="text" name="sections[0][name]" placeholder="e.g. Warming-Up" class="form-control" v-model="section.name">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-title="Remove" data-tooltip @click="removeSection(index)">
                                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Rounds</label>
                        <input type="number" name="sections[0][rounds]" class="form-control" placeholder="Optional" min="0" v-model="section.rounds">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">
                            Minutes
                        </label>
                        <input type="number" name="sections[0][minutes]" class="form-control" placeholder="Optional" min="0" v-model="section.minutes">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Measure</label>
                        <select name="sections[0][measure]" class="form-control" v-model="section.measure"> {{-- data-init-plugin="select2" --}}
                            <option :value="key" v-for="(measure, key) in measurements">@{{ measure }}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-block m-t-25">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="10%">
                        Reps
                    </th>
                    <th width="35%">
                        Movement
                    </th>
                    <th width="20%">
                        Measure
                    </th>
                    <th width="35%">
                        Remarks
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(movement, movementIndex) in section.movements">
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" name="sections[0][movements][0][reps]" class="form-control" min="0" v-model="movement.reps">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="sections[0][movements][0][movement]" class="form-control" v-model="movement.movement" @change="onMovementChange('', movement.movement)">
                            <optgroup :label="group" v-for="(options, group) in movements">
                                <option :value="key" v-for="(option, key) in options">@{{ option.name }}</option>
                            </optgroup>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="sections[0][movements][0][measure]" class="form-control" v-model="movement.measure" :disabled="!movement.movement">
                            <option :value="key" v-for="(measure, key) in options">@{{ measure }}</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea name="sections[0][movements][0][remark]" rows="1" class="form-control" v-model="movement.remarks"></textarea>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link text-danger" data-title="Remove" data-tooltip @click="removeMovement(index, movementIndex)">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-cons btn-complete" data-title="Add movement" data-tooltip @click="addMovement(index)">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

With this current set up it's adding the data in the second select box but it's always changing, so when adding a second movement row then both select boxes are changing there options based on the selected movement in the second row etc... it should only change based on the current row instead and section off course.

Maybe some of you could help me with this problem... if more info is needed please let me know :-)

Comment: A small sample on codepen or somewhere could help me debug it. But i think it might be the reference of the v-model. They probably pointing to the same model. Maybe give each movement an id or use index to make make it part of the v-model value. `v-model="movement[id].measure"` (or something like that)

Comment: @JeremyWalters thanks for your reaction it was due to the v-model, i didn't bind it correctly so i changed it to movement.movement.measure when the movement.movement has been set and now its working properly didn't need the onChange en computed functions at all :-)

Comment: Cool, glad you are sorted now